# Android: LinearLayout - not vertical or horizontal specified

Tags: android, layout

I was following a tutorial and i noticed that there was a linearlayout that was not specified vertical nor horizontal. I was told in another tutorial that it was basically required... what does it mean to have neither? is it bad? this was enclosed by another linearlayout which DID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It just means that `orientation` defaults to `horizontal`. So if the attribute is not there, the linear layout is a *horizontal* linear layout.

Answer (score 6):

When the `orientation` of a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is unspecified, it is using the **default**, which is `horizontal`.

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation):

> **android:orientation**
>
> Should the layout be a column or a row? Use "horizontal" for a row, "vertical" for a column. The default is horizontal.

It is also mentioned in the [Class Overview of LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html):

> **Class Overview**
>
> A Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single row... The default orientation is horizontal.

And also in [`setOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29):

> **public void setOrientation(int orientation)**
>
> ...
>
> Parameters
>
> *orientation*           Pass HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL. Default value is HORIZONTAL.

Answer (score 3):

default orientation for linearlayout is "horizontal"