# Editing the layout file

Tags: android, layout, button

I'm trying to edit the layout file so that two buttons appear side by side and not one above the other. The following is code from the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="225dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="12dip" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="12dip"
android:text="@string/dialog_text"
android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="Go"
android:text="@string/btn_go" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="stay"
android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As of right now, `btn_go` is appearing above `btn_stay_at_lifecycle`. What do I need to do to make `btn_stay_at_lifecycle` appear on the right of `btw_go`?

Thanks!

Comment: Now choose the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="225dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="12dip" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="12dip"
android:text="@string/dialog_text"
android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:onClick="Go"
    android:text="@string/btn_go" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:onClick="stay"
    android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `LinearLayout` is defined as `vertical`, so every item you add in it will be organized vertically.

If you need some items side by side, enclose those in a `LinearLayout` with property `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="12dip"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text"
        android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Go"
            android:text="@string/btn_go" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="stay"
            android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[The default value of `orientation` of a `LinearLayout` is `"horizontal"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124999/android-linearlayout-not-vertical-or-horizontal-specified). So even if you don't specify the `android:orientation` in the inner `LinearLayout`, it will arrange its contents side by side.

Answer (score 3):

Use following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="225dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="12dip" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="12dip"
android:text="@string/dialog_text"
android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="Go"
android:text="@string/btn_go" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="stay"
android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="225dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="12dip" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="12dip"
android:text="@string/dialog_text"
android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="Go"
        android:text="@string/btn_go" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="stay"
        android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dip" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
    android:text="@string/dialog_text"
    android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_go_to_new_App"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="Go"
    android:text="@string/btn_go" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_stay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="stay"
    android:text="@string/btn_stay_at_lifecycle" />
     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```